# NodeJs - mysql insert error

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following insert query:

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO `items` (`gameID`, `userID`, `bidID`, `value`, `imageUrl`, `itemName`) VALUES (' + gameID + ', 8, ' + rows.insertId + ', 3, https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/' + ourItems[i].classid + '/150fx125f, ' + ourItems[i].market_name + ')', function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
});
```

I'm getting the following error however:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should work on your strings and concatenations:

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO `items` (`gameID`, `userID`, `bidID`, `value`, `imageUrl`, `itemName`)
    VALUES ('" + gameID + "',
        8,
        '" + rows.insertId + "',
        3,
        'https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/" + ourItems[i].classid + "/150fx125f',
        '" + ourItems[i].market_name + "'
    )", function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

This should be syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should never build queries using that kind of concatenation.
You most likely will end up in a query that might break in future or even opens a possibility for sql injection.

If you use the `mysql` module then you should think over using the escape feature that are build in with the module ([Escaping query values](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#escaping-query-values)):

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO `items` SET ?', 
      {
         gameID: gameID,
         userID: 8,
         /* ... */
         imageUrl: 'https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/' + ourItems[i].classid + '/150fx125f'
        /* ... */ 
      }, function(err, rows, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
      });
```